# How to get Google Analytics url param information when using react-router Redirect to switch pages

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-router, react-ga

I am using redirect to go to the final page on my website. Within this redirect I feed it a bunch of url params that tell me what the user has done up to that point.

The problem is that when I added Google Analytics it did not pick up on any of the params that I would like to be able to gather data on. Here is the code in index.js:

```
import Analytics from 'react-router-ga';
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';

ReactGA.initialize('UA-11111111111-1');
ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);

const allGiftsPage = () => { return ( <Results quizType="allgifts" title="All Gifts" /> )}
const popularGiftsPage = () => { return ( <Results quizType="populargifts" title="Popular Gifts" /> )}
const quizResultsPage = () => { return ( <Results title="Results" /> )}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Fragment>
    <title>Find Their Gifts</title>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Analytics id='UA-111111111-1'>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App}></Route>
        <Route path="/results" component={quizResultsPage}></Route>
        <Route path="/allgifts" component={allGiftsPage}></Route>
        <Route path="/populargifts" component={popularGiftsPage}></Route>
      </Analytics>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Fragment>
  , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And here is the code that calls the redirect:

```
<Redirect to={`/results?`+
  `quizType=romanticquiz` +
  `&age=${this.state.age}`+
  `&gender=${this.state.gender}`+
  `&color=${this.state.color}`+
  `&vacation=${this.state.vacation}`+
  `&word=${this.state.word}`+
  `&prison=${this.state.prison}`
}
```

In Google Analytics a user that goes to this page with all of these params will just display '/results', but if you refresh on the results page you will get the full url with all of the params.

Is there a good way for me to get this functionality working without reworking a large portion of my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, not sure why you're using `react-ga` as well as `react-router-ga`.

Essentially the react-ga package is pretty flexible, the react-router-ga package is really just a simple component.

Let's look at why no-parameters are being passed through: https://github.com/fknussel/react-router-ga/blob/master/index.js#L53

Line 53: `window.ga('set', 'page', location.pathname);`

If you just want this to work, then changing that to include other parts of the URL will work. See reference on the [location object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp).

Another solution would be to use the react-ga solution for using it with router:

https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/blob/master/demo/app/withTracker.jsx